# JUnit ask user if test was successful?

Tags: java, junit, user-interaction

Does `JUnit` has a build it feature to ask user interactively about test succeeded?

I know `JUnit` is for automatic testing, but I have some sound generating classes which I want to test by ear and want in some rare one-run cases to test them manually and then add `@Ignore` to such tests.

Also I know I can popup dialog myself but I am wondering whether `JUnit` has something premade.

Comment: there is nothing as such... u can embed such logic in your code itself..

Comment: From personal experience this is an awful idea.  Someone implemented this system on legacy code and it did nothing nut ruin our build process.  We weren't able to have a one step build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [System.setIn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29) statements.

```
System.out.println("Confirm if you find blah blah working? Enter Y/N ");

System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
   // Pass the test case
} else {
   //Fail the test case
}
```